# Operator to choose upon the condition

Tags: java

I have a table which contain two columns in database `status` and `diff_id`  status column  may contain these values

```
DFG_SGG_RGRG
NULL
EF_SFEG_FTT
IFEF_RGG
```

`abc_id` may contain these values

```
null
43546
45346
45746
53465
```

Now I am getting these values in an object t ,so I have to make an condition where `status` column is null and `abc_id` should have value 435465666L so I have prefer to write an if like shown below please advise is it correct as I am confused between && operator || operator

```
if ( if f.getStatus()== null || abc_id() .longValue()==435465666L )
{
     //perform the logic
}
```

Please advise - is it correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

```
& = "and" 
&& = "and, but only if preceding condition was true" 
| = "or" 
|| = "or, but only if preceding condition was false"
```

Comment: It's useful to note that `&` and `|` are (also?) [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). When given numbers as input, they evaluate to numbers (e.g. `if (1 & 2)` doesn't compile, but `if (true & false)` does). I found them to have very limited use in practice, `&&` and `||` are usually preferred.

Comment: If I didn't already know, I probably wouldn't understand `"but only if preceding condition was true"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying:

- AND - use `&&`
- OR - use `||`

Remebmer also that `&&` takes precedence over `||`.

Answer (score 0):

If both conditions must be true you need to use the `&&` operator.

```
if (f.getStatus()== null && abc_id().longValue()==435465666L )
{
//perform the logic
}
```

Using the `&&` operator causes a condition to be true only if both conditions are true.  For example:

```
System.out.println(true && false); //prints false
System.out.println(false && false);  //prints false
System.out.println(true && true);  //prints true
System.out.println(false && true); //prints false
```

The `||` operator causes a condition to be true if one of the conditions is true.

```
System.out.println(true || false);  //prints true
System.out.println(false || false); //prints false
System.out.println(true || true);  //prints true
System.out.println(false || true); //prints true
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if (f.getStatus()== null && abc_id().longValue() == 435465666L )
{
   //perform the logic
}
```